# Leaking gutter down pipe/elbow junction

Tags: leak, pipe, gutters

I noticed a leak at the joint  of  `a down pipe` and `An-elbow`, yet rain water flows through the down pipe as expected but quite a large amount of water is dripping (*I outlined with red on the photo*).

There is an incline (*so that water flows down*), no holes in pipes. I tightened the connection but still for whatever reason it drips.

I looks to me that rain water traps in between the sloped pipe and the elbow and starts dripping to get its way out.

Any suggestions on what else I can improve to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When mine leaked from a similar location, it was from the screw. Typically, they use self-tapping screws to hold the pieces together. Since this is just thin aluminum, the interior piece gets pushed up as the screw taps through, and/or it leaves a jagged piece so water can get out.

All I did to fix it was to smear the bottom surface of the upper pipe with a generous glob of silicone caulk, slide it in, and replace the screw again.

Comment: The only drawback to this is that the silicone can glue the two pieces together. This becomes an issue when other repairs are necessary. It can be cut with a knife, but the thin aluminum can also be cut with a knife. The good news is that replacement pieces are dirt cheap, if one gets cut up.